# Parameter wildfly.skip not considered in command line deployment

Tags: maven, wildfly

In my maven project, I want to pass the `skip` parameter from command-line to `wildfly:deploy` goal.
I tried the following and used the `-X` option to check what parameters was considered.

My goal is to be able to skip wildfly deployment

Versions:

```
wildfly-maven-plugin 2.0.0.Final
maven 3.5.3
java 1.8.0_242
```

## 1

```
> mvn -X wildfly:deploy -Dwildfly.skip
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'wildfly' in the current project and in the plugin groups  [...]
```

## 2

```
> mvn -X wildfly:deploy -Dwildfly:wildfly.skip
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.0.Final:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
```

## 3

```
> mvn -X wildfly:deploy -Dwildfly:skip
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-plugin:2.0.0.Final:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
```

Tried some variants by adding `=true` or putting a space between `-D` and the parameter.

Nothing worked.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have it defined in your pom as `<skip>false</skip>`?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins No. Isn't it possible to set it from command line without using a maven profile for that?

Comment: It is, but you need to use `-Dwildfly.skip=true`.